# dotnet-trace collects only CPU_TIME and UNMANAGED_CODE_TIME

Tags: asp.net-core, perfview

I tries to collect profiling data of my ASP.NET Core 3.1 app on Ubuntu with "dotnet-trace collect" and view this data with PerfView but got only unmanaged code results.

What am I doing wrong? The app is definitely a managed app. Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Did you manage to get answer? Maybe libraries you are using call unmanaged code? Or this is time spent in CLR?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing symbols. Can you right click on lines with question marks and click 'Lookup Symbols' and see what you get?